# In C# what does expressionStack_xx_x mean?

Tags: c#, decompiling

I just decompiled an assembly file using .net reflector in C# and noticed a lot of expressionStack_xx_x  expressions which I never encountered before. From my understanding, the compiler replaces variables with this expression but I am not certain. What are they used for and are they generated by the compiler? Incomplete example of code below:

```
    public void DisplayDestinationBrowser()
{
System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog dialog2 = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog expressionStack_45_1 = dialog2;
string expressionStack_45_0 = "";
System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog expressionStack_10_2 = expressionStack_45_1;
string expressionStack_10_1 = expressionStack_45_0;
int expressionStack_10_0 = 0xf7b1;
}
```

Comment: Which decompiler did you use?

Comment: @svick I used .net reflector. Is that specific to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are generated by your decompiler.

The compiler does not save variable names at all.